# Machine.config alternative in Azure

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, web-config, azure-sql-database

I have a webservice which connects to a database on DEV / Production environments.

I'm managing both environments connection strings in the machine.config file of the servers.

For example, the machine.config in the production server will contain something like this:

```
<add key="MyDatabase" value="productsConnString..." />
```

and the dev server machine.config will have this settings:

```
<add key="MyDatabase" value="devConnString..." />
```

Naturally, when i connection to the database in code, i'm calling `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDatabase"]` and the correct connection string is loaded.

Is there i way i can achieve same abstraction level in Azure environment?

I read some articles which explain about Config transformations but if i use this i would need to Copy&Paste the connection strings to each Application (incase i have more than just that WebService).

Is there any alternative to machine.config in Azure? Maybe a subscription level Configuration file of some sort?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I would seriously consider using the cloud service configuration file (assuming this is a PaaS solution). It not only allows you to separate the application deployment package from the configuration settings (like you're doing), but also gives you the ability to adjust those changes "on the fly" to accommodate things like failover. If you take the extra step of creating your own configuration provider, it also gives you some simple ways to support both models.

Comment: Ok i've done some more reading but i still don't see where you're going with this. Are you saying that i can deploy to Production and to Dev with different settings? How exactly can i achieve this in a Cloud Service deployment?

Comment: You can have multiple cscfg files, one for dev, prod, prod2, whatever. When you do a deployment to Windows Azure, use the appropriate cscfg file for the environment you are deploying too. Some folks have even automated this by having their build/deploy servers know become aware of the environment and selecting the appropriate configuration files.

Comment: But then i would need to add these settings to each application! (ee db connectionstring, storage connectionstring, more environment level settings). How can i create reusable environment level configuration? I don't have a build server for now...

Comment: No, you just need to reference the setting name, and have a separate configuration file that gets to deployed to each environment. The cscfg file is your "reusable environment level configuration".

Comment: But i have 5 different cloud services. This means that i would need to copy & same configuration values for all of them so that's NOT reusable is it? or am i missing something

Comment: yes, you'll need 5 separate cscfg files. but you'll need 5 of them anyways. if you want to share settings between services, I usually put them into a storage account either table entries, or an XML file in an Azure blob.

Answer (score 1):

Concur with Brent - use the Cloud Service configuration file and get the setting with `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("settingsKey")` - this uses the Cloud Service config if you are in Azure or the Emulator first, if the key isn't found there it also looks in the web.config file in appSettings.

Comment: Is the cloud settings file is defined per subscription? how do i achieve environment separation using this file?

Comment: Cloud settings file are defined per deployment.  In your cloud project you will have a service definition file for each build configuration you have defined: e.g. ServiceConfiguration.DEV.cscfg, ServiceConfiguration.TEST.cscfg and ServiceConfiguration.PROD.cscfg.  When you package/publish the project you specify the build & service configurations.

Comment: Got it... Is there a way to save those settings on the server (same as i do with machine.config) and avoid making a different build for production? Currently (before migrating to azure) i can simply drop the same zipped file of my project from dev to production and it will work.

Comment: the cspkg is your "application zip". it contains the executable code. This can be the same file for both dev and prod. Its only the cscfg file that would need be different between the two.

Comment: No - Azure cloud services are VMs that get created with each new deployment.  You can't plan on saving anything in a cloud service.  You can use the BLOB for long term storage.  Preferred method for different environments though is the cscfg files as described.

Comment: But then i have to rewrite same configurations for each of my applications. Not to mention if one of the configurations change (like a webservice url) then i would need to update and redeploy all applications wouldn't I?

Comment: You are talking about an architecture solution - one solution that has already been suggested is to write a configuration/connection service to retrieve the settings - not dependent on Azure.  But remember, things will ALWAYS change and there will ALWAYS be a reason to redeploy.